# Is e^(-1/x) a flat function at x = 0?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Taylor series of e^(-1/x) at x = 0 shows that it is flat function on x= 0. But in every text on flat function I see the example of the function e^(-1/x^2) and not e^(-1/x). I am starting to think that there is flaw in my thinking and it might not be a flat function after all.

Comment: Define "flat function". The reason why many books use $e^{-x^{-2}}$ instead of $e^{-x^{-1}}$ is that you have to take one-sided limits (from above) instead of two-sided real limits to calculate the derivatives at zero.

Comment: What do you mean by flat function ? I here this first time.

Comment: As $x \rightarrow 0^-$, $\exp(-1/x)$ diverges.

Comment: How can $e^{-1/x}$ have a Taylor series at $x=0$?  It is not continuous there, so not differentiable.  See [How can I format mathematics here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to get started with MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: The function given by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x \leqslant 0 \\ e^{-1/x} &, x > 0 \end{cases}$$ is flat at $0$. The $e^{-1/x^2}$ example has the advantage of having nonzero values on both sides of $0$. The same could be achieved by $e^{-1/\lvert x\rvert}$.